# Spring MockMvc - How to test delete request with empty ID of REST controller?

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

I test my controller methods and I have a problem with a delete method. Here is my controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/wallet")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class WalletController {

    private final WalletService walletService;

@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<WalletDTO> deleteWalletById(@Valid @Min(1) @PathVariable Long id) {
    walletService.deleteWalletById(id);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("message", "You have successfully completed the delete of a Wallet!");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And my test:

```
@MockBean
private WalletService walletService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Test
void shouldThrowAnExceptionWhenWalletIdIsEmpty() throws Exception {
    //given
    WalletDTO walletDTO = new WalletDTO(1L, "Default", Instant.now());
    String id = "";

    //when
    ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(delete("/api/wallet/{}",id)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(Objects.requireNonNull(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(walletDTO))));

    //then
    result.andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

And I get status code 500 - Request method 'DELETE' not supported.
In console log I get:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:253)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1261)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.getHandler(TestDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
```

Can you tell me how to fix it?
I would like to test delete method with the passing of the ID parameter in cases where:

- ID is empty
- ID is equals zero

Comment: Probably you have another (non-delete) mapping on `/api/wallet/`!(?) (.."empty path variable" is really not cool/corner-case..i would live with the 500/try to convert to something customized (e.g. by introducing `@DeleteMapping("")` ... which returns 400-404;)

Answer (score 0):

The request path you are using in your test looks incorrect:

You should keep the URL template: `delete("/api/wallet/{id}", id)`
`{id}` represents the "placeholder" where `id` will be inserted in the URL.

So, if you want to test a URL like `/api/wallet/0` you would just set `id` to `0`.

That should work with your test.

Testing the "empty" ID is a different story:

If you pass an empty String to `{id}`, you are obviously calling `/api/wallet/` in the end. That's a different endpoint. Assuming that it might exist in your application, for instance as `GET /api/wallet`, the 500 Internal Server Error would be the expected response. Otherwise, it could also be 404 Not Found.